# Curl request not working using php script

Tags: php, curl

I have curl using voxbone API action method pass "did_dropdown" parameter value to get country wise dids. But another thing I am passing action method "didlist_type_city" parameter value not any response with pass country.

Note : Get url is working on terminal command line but postman api not any response get

```
curl -u xxxxx:xxxxx -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://sandbox.voxbone.com/ws-voxbone/services/rest/inventory/did?didIds='xxxxxx'&pageNumber=0&pageSize=1&countryCodeA3=IND"
```

Comment: can you please paste curl error here  ?

Comment: {
    "status": "1",
    "response": [],
    "response_code": null
}

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with PHP. Why did you tag PHP? Did you also write this curl request with PHP, and experience a problem? If so you'd have to show us that code before we can fix it. And what does PostMan have to do with it? The whole question is ambiguous and appear to have some information missing. Please explain everything clearly and precisely. We cannot read minds here.